# Syntax error in nested for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Below is a for loop written in Python2.7 and it is throwing a syntax error while executed in Python3.3. I am new to this language and would like any help to understand what kind of for look is this? Thanks. :)

```
for link in (links.pop(0) for _ in xrange(len(links))):
```

I have changed xrange() to range() while executing. 'links' is a list of urls.

Comment: Is there anything actually **in** the for loop?

Comment: This is not a nested loop, it's a loop with [a generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw). These are different things. Also note that this is a terrible way to loop over something. Also, when you get an error, post the actual error, then it's infinitely easier to see what the problem is.

Comment: "it is throwing a syntax error". Which one? How does it look?

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.3, [xrange](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) is not supported. You need to change the statement to use range.

[xrange](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) unlike range in Python 2.X returns an iterator where as [range](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#range) returns a list.
In Python 3.X, xrange has been dropped and instead the range now returns an iterator

Comment: Hi Abijit, yes I have replaced xrange by range but still there is a syntax error. Apart from that, is the above for loop syntactically correct?

Comment: @user1957908: There is no other syntax issue in this loop apart from the fact its useless to write the loop in this manner. Refer root's answer. Refer [Ideone Share](http://ideone.com/zrvTiT)

Answer (score 2):

this is the much the same as `for link in links:`, so why would you do it? Apart from that, it is syntactically correct in python3, if you said you replaced `xrange`.

If you want to consume `links` you can do something like:

```
links=[1,2,3,4,5]
links.reverse() #If the order matters
while links:
    print(links.pop())
    print(links)
```

out:

```
1
[5, 4, 3, 2]
2
[5, 4, 3]
3
[5, 4]
4
[5]
5
[]
```

Comment: It is marginally different, as `links` will be empty at the end of this - it's still a terrible idea, however.

Comment: @Lattyware -- Yes, added an example if op really wants to consume the list.